# lmer Get p values from anova

Tags: anova, mixed-models, p-value

`lmerTest` was designed as a wrapper to permit estimation of `p-values` from lmer mixed model analyses, using the Satterthwaite estimate of denominator degrees of freedom (ddf).  But `lmerTest` now appears to be broken.  It presently returns a message that there was an internal calculation error and returns only the lmer result (with no `p-values`). I have been able to calculate the `p-values` from the summary() function, using Dan Mirman's excellent code for calculating the Kenward-Rogers estimate of [ddf](http://mindingthebrain.blogspot.com/2014/02/three-ways-to-get-parameter-specific-p.html).  But I can't find equivalent code to calculate the `p-values` in an `anova` call on the lmer model.  I suspect that one just needs to feed `anova()` a ddf, but I can't figure out how to do that.

Thanks in advance to anyone that can suggest solutions for this problem.

Larry Hunsicker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

lmerTest returns the anova output of lme4 package whenever some computational error occurs in getting the Satterthwaite's approximation (such as e.g. in calculating the asymptotic variance covariance matrix). The lmerTest is not broken, it is just that there could be  examples  when the  Satterthwaite's approximation cannot be calculated. In my experience this occurs not often.

Comment: My apologies, Alexandra.  I understand now that the problem is with the calculation of Satterthwaite's approximation, and not with lmerTest.

Comment: I have now also found the answer to my question above.  The anova function in your lmerTest package gives the option of requesting the Kenwood-Roger approximation for ddf (ddf = 'Ken'), and that call of your anova gives exactly what I was looking for.  I have not found a way to request the K-R ddf approximation in your lmer function.  Is there a way to use K-R in your lmer as well?  If not, this might be a good addition to your package.  Thanks for lmerTest.

Comment: To use the Kenward-Roger's approximation for anova, you can write anova(model, ddf="kenw") and to use it in the summary function you can similarily write :  summary(model, ddf="kenw").  The lmerTest package uses the pbkrtest package's implementation of the Kenward-Roger's approximation